# How to extract specific value from xml string?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I would like to extract 1st two sentences under the `<P>` tag.

**for example(input string):**

```
<P align=justify><STRONG>Pricings<BR></STRONG>It was another active week for names leaving the database. The week's prints consisted of two ILS, and sever ITS.</P>
```

required output string:

```
It was another active week for names leaving the database. The week's prints consisted of two ILS, and sever ITS.
```

Currently, my function below is throwing the following error:

> System.Xml.XmlException: 'justify' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or ''

```
price = bottom.Substring(bottom.IndexOf("Pricings"), 8);

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(bottom);


XmlNodeList pList = doc.SelectNodes("/P[@align='justify']/strong");

foreach (XmlNode pValue in pList)
{
    string innerText = pValue.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
    innerText = result;
}
```

I am little unclear, how to go about resolving this issue.  Thank you for any further help.

Comment: Your HTML is not a valid XML string. It cannot be loaded using XmlDocument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not XML string, but HTML one.

Since HTML itself often can be not well-formed (and in your case it is not well-formed) , generally you can't use XML parsers to parse HTML.

Instead you can use [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (recommended way), or parse this text using regular expressions (generally not recommended, but sometimes possible).

Here is the sample code how to get youd data using HtmlAgility pack:

```
var s = "<P align=justify><STRONG>Pricings<BR></STRONG>It was another active week for names leaving the database. The week's prints consisted of two ILS, and sever ITS.</P>";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(s);

string result;
var p = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("p");
if (p.ChildNodes.Count == 2)
    result = p.ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
```

Note: Html Agility pack also available as NuGet package in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

i just do in in php/magento,  try this to solve .

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("../app/etc/local.xml") or die("X");$host = $xml->xpath('global/resources/default_setup/connection/host');$host = $host[0][0];$usernm = $xml->xpath('global/resources/default_setup/connection/username');$usernm = $usernm[0][0];$pwd = $xml->xpath('global/resources/default_setup/connection/password');$pwd = $pwd[0][0];$db = $xml->xpath('global/resources/default_setup/connection/dbname');$db = $db[0][0];$link = mysql_connect($host, $usernm, $pwd);
If (!$link) { die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db($db) or die ('Unable to select database');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalog_product_flat_1 Where shipping_price IS NULL AND type_id='simple'");
$noOfRecord = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

i use xml file as magento local.xml file which is located at magento/app/etc/local.xml..

Comment: Your answer looks totally unrelated to question. OP's question has nothing to do with php, magento, mysql and other stuff mentioned in your answer. Have you missed question to answer?